# Integrating codedUI tests into a build

Tags: msbuild, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have been creating codedUI tests for a website in VS2010.

What I would like to do is add these tests to our build process as a form of gated checkin. So if new code produced failed tests then it this code rejected.

does anyone have any experience or know of any resouces regarding this setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What source control repository \ build tools are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS for your builds you can easily integrate the tests into your build process.  If you are using something else for your build process you will need to have MSTEST installed on the build server and another machine to run the tests as an agent.